# Extract data from Raster files

Tags: python, raster, arcgis, arcpy

I have 3 raster files, the value ranges from 0 to 2. I am trying to extract grids where the value is greater than 1 in all 3 files. My desired output is a raster which contains the grids and values where value is more than 1.

How can I get the desired output in Python or ArcGIS?

Comment: This is not a free system design roundtable where we sit around discuss what you want.  Show your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

With *R* you can do

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) / 150

x <- all(s > 1)
plot(x)
```